# Pointwise convergent topology for the space of continuous functions $C(I)$ is properly contained in $T_{\infty}$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

For $I=[0,1]$ and $C(I):= \lbrace f:I \to \mathbb{R}:f\: \mbox{ is continuous} \rbrace$ I got the usual topology as induced by the supremum that is $$T_{\infty}:= \lbrace E\subset C(I):E=\cup \mathcal{A}   \rbrace$$

where each $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is an open ball

$$A=B(f,r):= \lbrace g \in C(I): \sup \lbrace |g(x)-f(x)|:x \in I\rbrace <r \rbrace$$.

Now $$\tau_{p}= \lbrace E \subset C(I):\mbox{there is }\:\mathcal{A} \subset B_{p}\: \mbox{with}\: E= \bigcup \mathcal{A} \rbrace$$

is a topology for $C(I)$ where

$$B_{p}= \lbrace [f;x_{1},...,x_{n},r]: f \in C(I),\:  n \in \mathbb{N}, \:x_{1},....,x_{n} \in I, \:r>0 \rbrace$$

and

$$[f;x_{1},...,x_{n},r]=\lbrace g \in C(I): \mbox{for every }\: 1\leq i \leq n\:(|f(x_{i}-g(x_{i}))|<r) \rbrace$$.

I want to prove that $T_{p} \subset T_{\infty}$.

So for a $E \in \tau_{p}$ I must show that $E \in \tau_{\infty}$. Lets take

$$[f;x_{1},...,x_{n},r] \in A \subset B_{p} \text{ where } A \in \bigcup \mathcal{A} \text{ and } \mathcal{A} \in B_{p}$$

So basically I need to prove that if $$g \in [f;x_{1},...,x_{n},r]$$ there is and $r'>0$ such $B(g,r') \in E$.Well Im confused proving this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that $B(f,r) \subseteq [f;x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n,r]$ for any $f \in C(I)$ and $r>0$, and $x_i \in I$.

So if $O$ is in $\tau_p$ and $f \in O$ then $f \in [g; x_1, \ldots,x_n, r] \subseteq O$ (as $f$ must be in some member of the basic family that $O$ is a union of) and take $s=\min(|r-|f(x_i)-g(x_i)|: i = 1,\ldots n)>0$ and then it is easily checked that $[f;x_1,\ldots,x_n; s] \subseteq [g; x_1, \ldots,x_n; r]$ and so

$$f \in B(f,s) \subseteq [f;x_1,\ldots,x_n; s] \subseteq [g; x_1, \ldots,x_n; r] \subseteq O$$

which shows that $f$ is an interior point of $O$ in $\tau_\infty$ as well, and as $f \in O$ is arbitrary, $\tau_p \subseteq \tau_\infty$